# NodeJS (General JS) comparing IP address

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, comparison

I'm using the following code to compare returned IP address (Using node-restify which is similar to express):

```
var checkIP = function (config, req) {
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress.split('.'),
        curIP,
        b,
        block = [];
    for (var i=0, z=config.ips.length-1; i<=z; i++) {
        curIP = config.ips[i].split('.');
        b = 0;
        // Compare each block
        while (b<=3) {
            (curIP[b]===ip[b] || curIP[b]==='*') ? block[b] = true : block[b] = false;
            b++;
        }
        // Check all blocks
        if (block[0] && block[1] && block[2] && block[3]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

`config.ips` contains an array which (as should be obvious from the code) can be specific or  wildcarded IPs.

This works, but it seems like there is a more efficient way to do this. Just curious if anyone has any suggestions on a way to simplify this or make it more efficient. My request time nearly doubled when I introduced this and I'd like to squeeze out some load time if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If my intuition is correct, you might be doing a bunch of extra work right now:

For each IP expression in your config.ips array, your code is parsing and comparing:

```
if (block[0] && block[1] && block[2] && block[3]) {
        return true;
 }
```

^^^ Note that you have already done work to get all 4 blocks in the iterations of calculating this expression 4 times per IP: `(curIP[b]===ip[b] || curIP[b]==='*')`, so the ANDing above is not preventing the overhead of the work that is already happening regardless.

I have 2 ideas for you:

1. Since IP addresses are strings anyways, the * notation lends itself to be suitable for a Regex to do the work, instead of your splitting and comparing? So maybe as a next step you could look into implementing a Regex to do the work, instead of .split() and compare, and test the performance of that?
2. Or maybe figure out how to avoid that overhead associated with comparing the parts all the time, and compare the wholes when you can? And then fall back into comparing the parts only when necessity requires it.
   If you want to read some C code, here's how [Apache does IP blacklisting](http://www.askapache.com/servers/mod_authz_host.c.html) behind the scenes. Look at the function named `in_domain` for some inspiration.

Good luck, hope this helps!